# Will a countable set of discontinuity with a limit point affect the integrability of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We all know that for a bounded function $f$ on interval $[a,b]$, if the set of discontinuity is countable, then the function is integrable. However, if the set of discontinuity on $[a,b]$  $X=\{t_i\}_{i\in N}$ satisfies 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}t_n=t_0$$
What changes do we need to make to prove that f is integrable. I think this condition is somewhat redundant because we already know the set of discontinuity is countable. I can't understand the meaning behind this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what this is supposed to mean. If you have a function that is discontinuous at countably many points $X=\{t_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ then there is always a subsequence of $X$ which has a limit (this is just the Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem). So adding the condition just restricts a bit to only those $X$ which converge as a whole.

But the way you state the question, seems to imply that $f$ is continuous **only** on $X$ as opposed to discontinuous only on $X$. In that case I don't think you can get integrability since the function could behave extremely badly everywhere except on a tiny set close to $t_0$.

Comment: Sorry this is my typo. X is the set of discontinuity. Thanks a lot.